# 'is not a valid Win32 application' error when using cordova adal plugin on Windows/Windows Mobile 10

Tags: cordova, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, adal

*I have added an issue for this problem to https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova, but I did not receive any response, so I'll try it here.*

I am trying to get my Cordova app to use AAD, but I cannot get it to work for the Windows/Windows Mobile targets.

When I call the plugin, it will try to call a native method, and I get the error: 'is not a valid Win32 application'. On my phone the error message is: 'The system cannot find the file specified'. This happens with my own app, but also when I run the sample from the 'sample' folder.

Repro details:

1. I am using Cordova 6.1.1 and I tried both 0.7.1 and 0.7.2-dev versions of the plugin.
2. The errors occur when targeting the platforms Windows 10 and Windows Phone (Universal). Android works fine.
3. I tested this on my laptop with Windows Insider Preview Build 14361 (and the previous build), my Phone with Windows Insiders Build 14256 and Emulators running both builds 10240 and 10586.
4. The issue occurs when using Cordova from the command line and also when I use Visual Studio Cordova Tools (version 14.0.60527.5, running in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 14.0.25123.00 2015 Update 2).

I have not enabled the SSO option.

I have attached the output of the sample application, after clicking the 'Create authentication context' button.

[image: Screenshot from the sample application.]

*Added simplified code from the sample, which can be found at https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova/tree/master/sample*

```
var AuthenticationContext;

var authority = 'https://login.windows.net/test353.onmicrosoft.com';
var resourceUrl = 'https://graph.windows.net/';
var appId = '1eed60fd-93bf-44c3-948b-d419b32b5ed6';
var redirectUrl = 'http://localhost:4400/services/aad/redirectTarget.html';

var tenantName = 'test353.onmicrosoft.com';
var endpointUrl = resourceUrl + tenantName;

var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function () {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function () {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', app.onDeviceReady, false);
    },

    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function () {
        // app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        AuthenticationContext = Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext;

        this.createContext();
    },

    createContext: function() {
        AuthenticationContext.createAsync(authority)
        .then(function (context) { app.authContext = context; }, app.error);
    },

    error: function(e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you post the code sample?

Comment: I [linked](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova/tree/master/sample) to the sample and added a simplified part of the code.

Comment: This was my first windows build and unfortunately i dont have required environment to build windows platform. But i tried testing the sample in android and i dont see the error mentioned in screenshot. Is there anyway to simulate this in android?